# IIS rewrite all request to a static url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have http://xyz.it/page1 to http://xyz.it/pageN and I need to redirect all pages to http://bar.it/foo and I thought I had solved it with this rule:

```
    <rule name="from-xyz-to-bar" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xyz\.it$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://bar.it/foo" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

But it doesn't work. What my rule is doing is redirecting http://xyz.it/page1 to http://bar.it/page1 and I don't understand where I am wrong.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have any other rules? Are you sure you are not encountering a cache issue?

Comment: Tried in incognito mode and on different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<rule name="from-xyz-to-bar" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://bar.it/foo" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Negative. The IIS site is the same for both domain, actually for few domains.